# Project in Gradle

Tags: groovy, build-automation, gradle

I'm new to gradle. I can see something like **project.getPlugins()** . what does this **project** refers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, the current project.

It's a [`Project` (docs)](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) and refers to the [current project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3aproject).

Higher-level documentation can be found in the [user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N101B3), and mid-level (usages regarding projects in the scripts) can be found in the [Writing Build Scripts docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec%3aproject_api).

Answer (score 3):

`project` is an object of type Project that refers to the current project. See the [groovydoc of this variable](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3aproject) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

project.getPlugins() == plugins == project.plugins.
project is the instance of current project build. plugins is one property of current build object(project). gradle can automatically create getter and setter for one property, that is why you can use getPlugins() as well.

Answer (score 0):

**project.plugins** is equvalent to **getProject().getPlugins()**

> Groovy automatically converts a property reference into a call to the appropriate getter or setter method.